# How do I disable headphone controls?

Tags: sound, lenovo, headphones, headset

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04 on a Lenovo Thinkpad X1 Carbon 7th Generation. I have Bose QC20 headphones which have volume and start/stop controls on them.

The headphones controls have started continually sending the play/pause command over and over. This is causing Ubuntu to pop up with a "Forbidden" icon every few seconds while they're plugged in. When I'm using Spotify they're continually making the music stop and start.

How can I disable these controls so I can just listen via the headphones without them sending this play/pause signal over and over?

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu, perhaps it causes from this problem, [static on Jack](https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/ThinkPad-X-Series-Laptops/ThinkPad-X1-Carbon-7th-Gen-Headphone-Jack-Static/td-p/4613541)